# Sony Z GPS issue (maybe after root)

Tags: gps, sony-xperia, geolocation

Apps on Sony Z could not find location using GPS after even like 15 minutes (about max I waited). I did not use location for some time, during which one thing I did is making root via Wondershare MobileGo.

Factory data reset did not help - neither it undid root access.

System check via `*#*#7378423#*#*` finds GPS location - in less then a minute.

I disabled and hide root via SuperSU app and still maps could not find location.

What could be done to help apps find location?

ADDED:
Installed GPS Test app. GPS Test is finding satellites after several minutes. After satellites are found by GPS Test, maps (e.g. MAPS.ME) start working (Pokemon Go still says 'No GPS').
Still interested why location is not working w/out such trick and what can be done about it.